# can not running javafx project on netbeans8-2

Tags: java, javafx-2, netbeans-8.2

i can not run a simple javaFx project on netbeans8-2

i am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS and openjdk
but openjfx can not install on my system (in fact it will install but files that are here [ https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/openjfx/filelist ] will not exist at their place)

for example file jfxrt.jar was not exist in the /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/ directory

so i copy this file with sudo cp command

but i can not find two files that their names are javafxpackager.1.gz and javapackager.1.gz on my system and internet

and so on the errors are this when i run my program

```
run:
Exception in thread "main"      java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._isDisplayValid()Z
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:267)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
... 5 more
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._isDisplayValid()Z
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._isDisplayValid(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.isDisplayValid(GtkApplication.java:83)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:67)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
... 9 more
/home/*/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

that link refers to

```
<java classpath="${classpath}" classname="${classname}" dir="${work.dir}" jvm="${platform.java}" fork="true" failonerror="${java.failonerror}">
```

is my problem related to openjfx?